# Firestore rules not picking up custom claims

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I can't get custom claims to work in the firestore rules.
I'm using nodeJS (local) to set the custom claims and initialize with the service-account from firebase. The user token is automatically added to the request headers and validates fine on node.

```
// Initialize
admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as admin.ServiceAccount), // Typing is wrong google!
  databaseURL: `https://${serviceAccount.project_id}.firebaseio.com`
});

// Add custom claims for additional privileges.
const payload = await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(decodedToken.sub, { 
customClaims })
  .then(() => ({ ...decodedToken, customClaims }))
  .catch(() => void 0);
if (!payload) { res.status(401).json({ error: 'Error setting custom claims on token' }); return; }
```

Custom claims object:

```
// Define custom claims
const customClaims: CustomClaims = {
  serverAuth: true,
  domain: domainOfUser,
  developer: isDeveloper,
  admin: isAdmin,
};
```

Angular Fire 2: User logs in with google redirect then refresh the token:

```
if (!this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser) { return Promise.reject('User object not found in fireAuth service'); }
return this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);
```

When that's al done I do: (the fireAuthService is a custom service that handles some auth stuff)

```
// On user change
this.fireAuthService.user$.pipe(
  map(userAuth => { if (!userAuth) { this.userSource.next(null); } return userAuth; }),
  filter(notNullOrUndefined),
  switchMap(async userAuth => {
    const userDoc = this.userCollection.doc<UserDb>(userAuth.uid);
    const exists = await userDoc.get().toPromise().then(user => user.exists)
      .catch(() => this.fireAuthService.signOut());
    if (!exists) {
      const res = await this.serverService.createNewUser(userAuth).catch(() => void 0);
      if (!res) { this.fireAuthService.signOut(); }
    }
    return userAuth;
  }),
  switchMap(userAuth => this.userCollection.doc<UserDb>(userAuth.uid).valueChanges())
).subscribe(async userDb => {
  await this.fireAuthService.getAuthToken();
  const isAdmin = await this.fireAuthService
    .getTokenPayload()
    .then(payload => (payload.claims.customClaims as CustomClaims).admin);
  this.userSource.next(new CurrentUser(userDb, this.serverService, isAdmin));

  runAngularFire();
});
```

On the payload are all my custom claims at this point. The firestore calls on the user doc firestore calls are secured by only checking the uid in the firestore rules and this works.

At this point I set up my listeners. They fail with the error:

> Missing or insufficient permissions.

The firestore rules are setup as followed:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

  // Allow users to read documents in the user's collection
  match /users/{userId} {
    allow read: if request.auth.token.sub == userId;
  }

  // Allow only reads to the db
  match /{document=**} {
    allow read: if request.auth.token.serverAuth == true;
  }
}
```

I've tried just about anything and I'm at a loss. Any suggestion?
Many thanks in advance!

Edit: I also checked the token send out on channel?database=... This token has the custom claims...

Comment: Did you log the user out and back in again?  Custom claims won't show up until a new token is generated or refreshed.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client

Comment: You reference a `customClaims` object in the call to `setCustomUserClaims`, but you don't show its contents.  So it's impossible to see if you're actually setting the same field that's being referenced in the rule.

Comment: @DougStevenson Done. Yes I'm refreshing the tokens.

Comment: It's not clear to me what is the query that's failing, and which rule should be allowing it.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry there was still a string 'true' when debugging. The goal for this is to allow only reads when the server has done some validation. I would like to check that the server has set custom claims.

Comment: Does the client see that it has serverAuth=true from its perspective?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, that's what so weird. Also the first channel?database... send out from chrome dev network has the correct token.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce.  Custom claims in security rules are working OK for me when accessed through the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the help. A night of sleep helped ;)

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you so much! that was exactly my problem. On the backend (firebase cloud functions) I was updating the user's custom claims, but not getting a refresh token for the frontend to use for the db calls. just had to add  
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.getIdToken(true);   (im in flutter)
after my function that updated it on the backend

Answer (score 1):

After a night of sleep I noticed my error:

```
const payload = await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(decodedToken.sub, { customClaims });
```

To:

```
const payload = await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(decodedToken.sub, customClaims);
```

Also I did test the rules on a object. Objects probably don't work in rules.

Comment: with destructuring, your first incorrect code would evaluate as `{ customClaims: {...}}` when it's expecting just the object itself. You set a claim named `customClaims` by accident.